# Getting Table Wrapped In <tbody> Automatic

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Is there any good and minimal plugin which fix `<thead>` or first row? And dont add `<tbody>` automatically.**

When i am using `<thead>` to wrap the first row (directly in HTML Table) , then everything is working right as it should for my table. But when i am adding `<thead>` to wrap the first row (not HTML but through jquery) `$("tr").first().wrap("<thead></thead>");` then it is working but not displaying as it should, because first its wrapping the whole table in `<tbody>` automatically then adding `<thead>` in first row.

Please tell me how to solve this because my tables don't have `<thead>` in HTML. But I need it to fix the first row when scrolling, because it is requirement in all jQuery Plugins to have `<thead>` to fix first row, please help

---

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/seky66cb/ (adding `<thead>` with HTML)

Not Working For Me: http://jsfiddle.net/seky66cb/1/ (adding `<thead>` with jQuery)

---

CODE (Not Working As Expected):

Library: `jQuery: 2.1.3`

HTML:

```
<table class="gridView" id="table2">

<tr>
<th> Culture Name </th>
<th> Display Name </th>
<th> Culture Code </th>
<th> ISO 639x </th>
</tr>

<tr class="grid">
<td> af-ZA </td>
<td> Afrikaans - South Africa </td>
<td> 0x0436 </td>
<td> AFK </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> sq-AL </td>
<td> Albanian - Albania </td>
<td> 0x041C </td>
<td> SQI </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-DZ </td>
<td> Arabic - Algeria </td>
<td> 0x1401 </td>
<td> ARG </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-BH </td>
<td> Arabic - Bahrain </td>
<td> 0x3C01 </td>
<td> ARH </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-EG </td>
<td> Arabic - Egypt </td>
<td> 0x0C01 </td>
<td> ARE </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-IQ </td>
<td> Arabic - Iraq </td>
<td> 0x0801 </td>
<td> ARI </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-JO </td>
<td> Arabic - Jordan </td>
<td> 0x2C01 </td>
<td> ARJ </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-KW </td>
<td> Arabic - Kuwait </td>
<td> 0x3401 </td>
<td> ARK </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-LB </td>
<td> Arabic - Lebanon </td>
<td> 0x3001 </td>
<td> ARB </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-LY </td>
<td> Arabic - Libya </td>
<td> 0x1001 </td>
<td> ARL </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-MA </td>
<td> Arabic - Morocco </td>
<td> 0x1801 </td>
<td> ARM </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-OM </td>
<td> Arabic - Oman </td>
<td> 0x2001 </td>
<td> ARO </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-QA </td>
<td> Arabic - Qatar </td>
<td> 0x4001 </td>
<td> ARQ </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-SA </td>
<td> Arabic - Saudi Arabia </td>
<td> 0x0401 </td>
<td> ARA </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-SY </td>
<td> Arabic - Syria </td>
<td> 0x2801 </td>
<td> ARS </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-TN </td>
<td> Arabic - Tunisia </td>
<td> 0x1C01 </td>
<td> ART </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ar-AE </td>
<td> Arabic - United Arab Emirates </td>
<td> 0x3801 </td>
<td> ARU </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> ar-YE </td>
<td> Arabic - Yemen </td>
<td> 0x2401 </td>
<td> ARY </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> hy-AM </td>
<td> Armenian - Armenia </td>
<td> 0x042B </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> Cy-az-AZ </td>
<td> Azeri (Cyrillic) - Azerbaijan </td>
<td> 0x082C </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> Lt-az-AZ </td>
<td> Azeri (Latin) - Azerbaijan </td>
<td> 0x042C </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> eu-ES </td>
<td> Basque - Basque </td>
<td> 0x042D </td>
<td> EUQ </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> be-BY </td>
<td> Belarusian - Belarus </td>
<td> 0x0423 </td>
<td> BEL </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> bg-BG </td>
<td> Bulgarian - Bulgaria </td>
<td> 0x0402 </td>
<td> BGR </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> ca-ES </td>
<td> Catalan - Catalan </td>
<td> 0x0403 </td>
<td> CAT </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> zh-CN </td>
<td> Chinese - China </td>
<td> 0x0804 </td>
<td> CHS </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> zh-HK </td>
<td> Chinese - Hong Kong SAR </td>
<td> 0x0C04 </td>
<td> ZHH </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> zh-MO </td>
<td> Chinese - Macau SAR </td>
<td> 0x1404 </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> zh-SG </td>
<td> Chinese - Singapore </td>
<td> 0x1004 </td>
<td> ZHI </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> zh-TW </td>
<td> Chinese - Taiwan </td>
<td> 0x0404 </td>
<td> CHT </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> zh-CHS </td>
<td> Chinese (Simplified) </td>
<td> 0x0004 </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> zh-CHT </td>
<td> Chinese (Traditional) </td>
<td> 0x7C04 </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> hr-HR </td>
<td> Croatian - Croatia </td>
<td> 0x041A </td>
<td> HRV </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> cs-CZ </td>
<td> Czech - Czech Republic </td>
<td> 0x0405 </td>
<td> CSY </td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> da-DK </td>
<td> Danish - Denmark </td>
<td> 0x0406 </td>
<td> DAN </td>
</tr>
<tr class="gridAlternada">
<td> div-MV </td>
<td> Dhivehi - Maldives </td>
<td> 0x0465 </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="grid">
<td> nl-BE </td>
<td> Dutch - Belgium </td>
<td> 0x0813 </td>
<td> NLB </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$( "tr" ).first().wrap( "<thead></thead>" );

(function ($) {
    $.fn.freezeHeader = function (params) {
        var copiedHeader = false;
        var idObj = this.selector.replace('#', '');
        var container;
        var grid;
        var conteudoHeader;
        var openDivScroll = '';
        var closeDivScroll = '';

        if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
            divScroll = '<div id="hdScroll' + idObj + '" style="height: ' + params.height + '; overflow-y: scroll">';
            closeDivScroll = '</div>';
        }

        grid = $('table[id$="' + idObj + '"]');
        conteudoHeader = grid.find('thead');

        if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
            if ($('#hdScroll' + idObj).length == 0) {
                grid.wrapAll(divScroll);
            }
        }

        var obj = params && params.height !== undefined
           ? $('#hdScroll' + idObj)
           : $(window);

        if ($('#hd' + idObj).length == 0) {
            grid.before('<div id="hd' + idObj + '"></div>');
        }

        obj.scroll(function () { freezeHeader(); })

        function freezeHeader() {

            if ($('table[id$="' + idObj + '"]').length > 0) {

                container = $('#hd' + idObj);
                if (conteudoHeader.offset() != null) {
                    if (limiteAlcancado(params)) {
                        if (!copiedHeader) {
                            cloneHeaderRow(grid);
                            copiedHeader = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        if (($(document).scrollTop() > conteudoHeader.offset().top)) {
                            container.css("position", "absolute");
                            container.css("top", (grid.find("tr:last").offset().top - conteudoHeader.height()) + "px");
                        }
                        else {
                            container.css("visibility", "hidden");
                            container.css("top", "0px");
                            container.width(0);
                        }

                        copiedHeader = false;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function limiteAlcancado(params) {
            if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
                return (conteudoHeader.offset().top <= obj.offset().top);
            }
            else {
                return ($(document).scrollTop() > conteudoHeader.offset().top && $(document).scrollTop() < (grid.height() - conteudoHeader.height() - grid.find("tr:last").height()) + conteudoHeader.offset().top);
            }
        }

        function cloneHeaderRow() {
            container.html('');
            container.val('');
            var tabela = $('<table style="margin: 0 0;"></table>');
            var atributos = grid.prop("attributes");

            $.each(atributos, function () {

                if (this.name != "id") {
                    tabela.attr(this.name, this.value);
                }
            });

            tabela.append('<thead>' + conteudoHeader.html() + '</thead>');

            container.append(tabela);
            container.width(conteudoHeader.width());
            container.height(conteudoHeader.height);
            container.find('th').each(function (index) {
                var cellWidth = grid.find('th').eq(index).width();
                $(this).css('width', cellWidth);
            });

            container.css("visibility", "visible");

            if (params && params.height !== undefined) {
                container.css("top", obj.offset().top + "px");
                container.css("position", "absolute");
            } else {
                container.css("top", "0px");
                container.css("position", "fixed");
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#table1").freezeHeader({ 'height': '300px' });
        $("#table2").freezeHeader();

       $("#tbex1").freezeHeader();
            $("#tbex2").freezeHeader();
            $("#tbex3").freezeHeader();
            $("#tbex4").freezeHeader();     



        })
```

CSS:

```
#jquery-script-menu {
position: fixed;
height: 90px;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-top: 5px solid #316594;
background: #fff;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
z-index: 999999;
padding: 10px 0;
-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;
-moz-box-sizing:content-box;
box-sizing:content-box;
}

.jquery-script-center {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.jquery-script-center ul {
width: 212px;
float:left;
line-height:45px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
}
.jquery-script-center a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
.jquery-script-ads {
width: 728px;
height:90px;
float:right;
}
.jquery-script-clear {
clear:both;
height:0;
}

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", "Myriad Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    background:#fefefe;
    color:#333;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #fff;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
h1{
    font-size:30px;
    color:#666;
}
h2{
    font-size:20px;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;
    margin:15px 0px 20px 0px;
}
a{
    color:#555;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
    color:#222;
}
p{
    padding:5px 0px;
}
.wrapper{
    width:960px;
    margin:20px auto;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

    /* ----------->>> GridView <<<----------*/
        .gridView
        {
            width: 100%;
            clear: both;
            margin: 10px 0;
            border: medium none !important;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .gridView tr td
        {
            border: 1px solid #aaa;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .gridView thead tr, .footer
        {
            font: bold 11px Arial;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* --->>> HeaderStyle (cabeçalho) <<<---*/
        .gridView thead tr
        {
            color: #333;
            background: #fff url(../images/bg-header-grid.png) bottom repeat-x;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 25px;
        }
        .gridView thead tr th
        {
            border: 1px solid #E2E6E6;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #E5E5E5;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .gridView thead tr a
        {
            font: bold 11px Arial, Verdana;
            color: #333;
            padding: 0 0 0 10px;
            text-decoration: underline;
            background: url(../images/Icones/ico-ordem.gif) left no-repeat;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .gridView thead tr a:hover
        {
            color: #06c;
            background: url(../images/Icones/ico-ordem-hover.gif) left no-repeat;
        }

        /* ---->>> FooterStyle (rodapé) <<<------*/
        .footer
        {
            height: 20px;
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        /*PagerStyle*/
        .footer a, .footer span
        {
            color: #555;
            padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
            border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
            background: #F1F1F1 url(../images/bg-pg.png) bottom repeat-x;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .footer a:hover
        {
            color: #C40B17;
            background-color: #fff;
            background-image: none;
            border: 1px solid #890812;
        }
        .footer span
        {
            color: #fff;
            background: #D7403F url(../images/bg-pg-focus.png) bottom repeat-x;
            border: 1px solid #890812;
        }


        /* ------------>>> Grid <<<--------------*/
        .grid, .gridAlternada, .gridDestacada
        {
            font: 11px Arial,Verdana;
            text-align: left;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .grid:hover, .gridAlternada:hover, .gridDestacada:hover
        {
            color: #000;
            background: #D4E5F6 url(../images/bg-dia.png) 0 0 repeat-x;
        }

        .grid
        {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        /*RowStyle*/
        .gridAlternada
        {
            background-color: #eee;
        }
        /*AlternatingRowStyle*/
        .gridDestacada
        {
            background-color: #FFE082;
            color: #333;
        }
        /*SelectedRowStyle / EditRowStyle*/


        /* -------->>> Link Grid's <<<-----------*/
        .grid a, .gridAlternada a, .gridDestacada a
        {
            color: #384249;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .grid a:hover, .gridAlternada a:hover, .gridDestacada a:hover
        {
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is after wrapping the first row in the `<thead>`, move the `<thead>` out of the `<tbody>` and prepend it to the table.

```
$( "tr" ).first().wrap( "<thead></thead>" ).parent().prependTo('.gridView');
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udh07rz2/)

Comment: is there any good and minimal plugin which fix `<thead>` or first row?

Comment: I'm not aware of any plugins for this, it shouldn't be too hard to make though.